# unknown class name 'MyCentralGraphicsItem'; did you mean 'MyCentralRectItem'?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a bug that I have been trying to fix for hours, it is not a big deal but I really don't know what to do here. I am using Qt, but there is no need to know Qt, just C++ and OOP.

[This is the repository](https://github.com/apregoe/reall) in which I am pushing all the project. Don't worry about all the files, the ones that I am having problem with are MyCentralGraphicsItem and MyCentralRectItem. QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem is an abstract class provided by Qt. I inherited from it to create my custom Items.

You can find the output error in the bug file in the repository.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to help you debug your projects (well, ultimately it might be, but not that way)... Otherwise your problem probably is that `MyCentralGraphicsItem` isn't completely defined (either only declared or more likely not declared at all) whereas inheritance requires the full definition (according to the error message).

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it: MyCentralGraphicsItem.h depends on MyDropGraphicsScene.h which depends on MyCentralRectItem.h which depends on MyCentralGraphicsItem.h there's a cycle in your `include`s. You should break that cycle by just forward declaring the needed class in one of these files instead of including the header. (Edit: actually just remove `#include "MyCentralRectItem.h"` in MyDropGraphicsScene.h it isn't needed and put it in MyDropGraphicsScene.cpp instead)

Comment: Thanks! It completely solved the problem.